music unexpectedly play when app is close | Flutter
i have an application and i play music for user while using it.
so i handle when user is not in resuming mode the song should stop. it works very fine but i found a bug.
the bug is when i minimize the app and go to some app like Instagram and see a reels when tap the home screen and suddenly the music play. but my AppLifecycleState doesn't change.
this is my code :
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    LayoutBuilder(
      builder: ((context, constraints) {
        Responsive().init(constraints: constraints);
        return const MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: AppRouter(),
        );
      }),
    ),
  );
}

class AppRouter extends StatefulWidget {
  const AppRouter({super.key});

  @override
  State<AppRouter> createState() => _AppRouterState();
}

class _AppRouterState extends State<AppRouter> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  List<AppLifecycleState> appStates = [];

  Future<void> _playAudio() async {
    await QUser().audioPlayer.play(AssetSource(QUser().audioSource));
  }

  bool wasAudioPlaying = true;

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    log(state.toString());

    if (appStates.length > 10) {
      final last = appStates[appStates.length - 1];
      appStates = [];
      appStates.add(last);
    }
    appStates.add(state);

    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      if (wasAudioPlaying) {
        await QUser().audioPlayer.resume();
      }
    } else {
      if (appStates[appStates.length - 2] == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
        if (QUser().audioPlayer.state == PlayerState.playing) {
          wasAudioPlaying = true;
        } else if (QUser().audioPlayer.state == PlayerState.paused) {
          wasAudioPlaying = false;
        }
      }

      await QUser().audioPlayer.pause();
    }
  }

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
  }

  @override
  dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<AppBloc>(
      create: (context) => AppBloc(),
      child: BlocConsumer<AppBloc, AppState>(
        listener: (context, state) async {
          if (state.isLoading) {
            LoadingScreen().show(
              context: context,
              text: "منتظر بمانید",
            );
          } else {
            LoadingScreen().hide();
          }

          if (state.exception is InternetConnectionException) {
            await showErrorDialog(
              context: context,
              text: "ارتباط خود را با اینترنت بررسی نمیایید",
            );
          } else if (state.exception is GenericException) {
            await showErrorDialog(
              context: context,
              text: "مشکلی پیش آمده، لطفا دوباره تلاش کنید",
            );
          }
        },
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state is OnboardingAppState) {
            return const OnBoardingView();
          } else if (state is RegisterAppState) {
            return const RegisterView();
          } else if (state is AppRulesAppState) {
            return const AppRulesView();
          } else if (state is LoginAppState) {
            return const LoginView();
          } else if (state is ChooseProfileIconAppState) {
            return ChooseProfileIconView(
              isRegistered: state.isRegistered,
            );
          } else if (state is ConfirmNumberAppState) {
            return ConfirmNumberView(
              isRegistered: state.isRegistered,
            );
          } else if (state is ProfileAppState) {
            return const ProfileView();
          } else if (state is HomeAppState) {
            if (QUser().audioPlayer.state == PlayerState.paused) {
              return HomeView(
                runAnimation: state.runAnimation,
              );
            } else {
              QUser().audioPlayer.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.loop);
              _playAudio();
              return HomeView(
                runAnimation: state.runAnimation,
              );
            }
          } else if (state is RulesAppState) {
            return const RulesView();
          } else if (state is CommentAppState) {
            return const CommentView();
          } else if (state is CategoryAppState) {
            return const CategoryView();
          } else if (state is PickPlayerAppState) {
            return const PickPlayerView();
          } else if (state is SelectTimeAppState) {
            return const SelectTimeView();
          } else if (state is GameAppState) {
            return GameView(
              question: state.question,
              player: state.player,
              seconds: state.seconds,
            );
          } else if (state is GameEndAppState) {
            return const GameEndView();
          } else if (state is InitialAppState) {
            return const InitialApp();
          } else {
            context.read<AppBloc>().add(const InitialAppEvent());
            return const Scaffold(
              body: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

when my app is closed or minimized the song shouldn't play at all. i handle it very well but when i play a sound from somewhere else like Instagram the app doesn't work properly
